# PySpark DataFrame: get row wise sorted column names based on column values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am a beginner in PySpark and am looking for a solution for my issue. Actually, I want to sort my column name by column name.

My PySpark data frame looks like below:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  5|  2|  1|
|  1|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+
```

And it should be sorted in the below format:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| ID| p1| p2| p3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  a|  b|  c|
|  1|  c|  b|  a|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I have tried several methods to sort it but it's not working. I wish you could help me.

Comment: what is your version of spark ?

Comment: I am using spark latest version 3.0, thanks for answer i will test it and will try to understand!!

Comment: no, spark data-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not know you spark version, I assume it is lower than 2.4.
So I will use an UDF to perform that task.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def sort_array(in_array):
    in_array.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return [i[0] for i in in_array]

df.withColumn(
    "a", F.array(F.lit("a"), F.col("a"))
).withColumn(
    "b", F.array(F.lit("b"), F.col("b"))
).withColumn(
    "c", F.array(F.lit("c"), F.col("c"))
).withColumn(
    "data", F.array(F.col("a"), F.col("b"), F.col("c"))
).withColumn(
    "prio", sort_array(F.col("data"))
).select(
    "ID",
    F.col("prio").getItem(0).alias("p1"),
    F.col("prio").getItem(1).alias("p2"),
    F.col("prio").getItem(2).alias("p3"),
).show()


+---+---+---+---+
| ID| p1| p2| p3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  c|  b|  a|
|  1|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
```

---

**EDIT** : Dynamic mode

```py
@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def sort_array(in_array):
    in_array.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return [i[0] for i in in_array]


col_list = [col for col in df.columns if col != "ID"]


df.withColumn(
    "data", F.array(*(F.array(F.lit(col), F.col(col)) for col in col_list))
).withColumn(
    "prio", sort_array(F.col("data"))
).select(
    "ID", *(F.col("prio").getItem(i).alias(f"p{i+1}") for i in range(len(col_list)))
).show()
```

Comment: can we make it little dynamic, which we can apply on any df

Answer (score 0):

try this-

> In scala, but can be used in python. with minimal change

**`spark>=2.4`**

```scala
  df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+---+---+---+
      * |ID |a  |b  |c  |
      * +---+---+---+---+
      * |0  |5  |2  |1  |
      * |1  |3  |4  |5  |
      * +---+---+---+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
      */

    val ignoredCol = "ID"
    val columns = df.columns.filterNot(_ == ignoredCol).map(c => struct(col(c).as("val"), lit(c).as("name")))
    val l = columns.length

    val p = df.withColumn("arr", array_sort(array(columns: _*)))
      .select(col(ignoredCol) +:
      Range(0, l).map(i => $"arr".getItem(i).getField("name").as(s"p${l-i}")): _*)
    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+---+---+---+
      * |ID |p3 |p2 |p1 |
      * +---+---+---+---+
      * |0  |c  |b  |a  |
      * |1  |a  |b  |c  |
      * +---+---+---+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- p3: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- p2: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- p1: string (nullable = true)
      */
```